# How to return multiple datasets for a multi valued parameter?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement to generate a SSRS report to get multiple invoices based on the multiple order numbers given as parameters. Each page should have only 1 invoice per order.

Answer (score 0):

In your row grouping, go to Page Breaks, and select 'Between each instance of a group'. Make sure it is ticked and not solid.